# how can I narrow dataclass annotations (i.e., how can I update type hints after handling default None in post_init)?

Tags: python, mypy

I have a dataclass that can take a keyword value, or, if no value is specified, infer a value from other attributes.

```
import dataclasses

@dataclasses.dataclass
class RelatedValues:
    primary: float
    _: dataclasses.KW_ONLY
    secondary: float | None = None

def __post_init__(self):
    if self.secondary is None:
        self.secondary = self.primary
```

This code works, but it leaves me stuck with `float | None` as the type hint for `.secondary` even though `.secondary` *cannot possibly* be `None` after `__post_init__`.

`cast`-ing `self.secondary` in `__post_init__` doesn't work. This does:

```
NULL_FLOAT = float(int(uuid.uuid4())

@dataclasses.dataclass
class RelatedValues:
    primary: float
    _: dataclasses.KW_ONLY
    secondary: float = NULL_FLOAT

def __post_init__(self):
    if self.secondary == NULL_FLOAT:
        self.secondary = self.primary
```

But it feels distinctly non-Pythonic.

This also works:

```
@dataclasses.dataclass
class RelatedValues:
    primary: float
    _: dataclasses.KW_ONLY
    _secondary: float | None = None

def __post_init__(self):
    if self._secondary is None:
        self.secondary = self.primary
    else:
        self.secondary = self._secondary
```

or this:

```
@dataclasses.dataclass
class RelatedValues:
    primary: float
    _: dataclasses.KW_ONLY
    _secondary: float | None = None

@property
def secondary(self) -> float:
    if self._secondary is None:
        self.secondary = self.primary
    else:
        self.secondary = self._secondary
```

But the latter two are just mangling my kwargs for the sake of type narrowing, which kind of feels wrong.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `secondary` will always be assigned a non-`None` value, it should not be typed as `float | None` in the first place. It's only the *argument* to `__init__`, used to initialize `self.secondary`, that might be `None`.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field, InitVar


@dataclass
class RelatedValues:
    primary: float
    secondary: float = field(init=False)
    secondary_: InitVar[float|None] = None

    def __post_init__(self, secondary_):
        if secondary_ is None:
            secondary_ = self.primary
        self.secondary = secondary_
```

These hoops are only necessary if you don't want to provide your own `__init__` method in the first place. For example,

```
@dataclass(init=False)
class RelatedValues:
    primary: float
    secondary: float

    def __init__(self, primary: float, secondary: float = None):
        if secondary is None:
            secondary = primary
        self.primary = primary
        self.secondary = secondary
```

Comment: Thank you, and you're right. But this sort of breaks when you get to non-positional args. Then your keyword args have mangled names like _arg. I should have mentioned this in my original post. Will update. Thanks again.

Comment: Dataclasses are not a panacea. I got lazy in the second example, writing `p` and `s` for `primary` and `secondary`, respectively, but that approach lets you preserve the  desired parameter names.

Comment: It might be nice if `dataclasses` provided someway to modify the parameter name of an `InitVar` pseudo-field, e.g. a hypothetical `secondary_: InitVar[float|None]["secondary"] = None`. As the second example demonstrates, the parameter name can be equivalent to the attribute name without them needing to have the same type.

Comment: I'm terribly afraid you're right and this is the only way to go about it. I will accept the answer tomorrow if no one comes up with a really pleasant surprise. I often work with matplotlib or xml where there are SCADS of parameters, and constantly struggle to find the best way to produce a tidy, flexible arg cache / generator.

Comment: Definitely. There are solutions (two workable ones here so far), but they all feel pretty extreme given that you're only trying to help mypy keep up with straightforward code and common practice.